# How to search for an object using two different search keys used seperately at different times?

Tags: c++, data-structures, key

Say I have the following:

```
class Order
{
public:

   Order(int id, double p) : order_id(id), price(p) {}
   int get_order_id() { return order_id; }
   double get_price() { return price; }


private:
   int order_id;
   double price;
};

std::multimap<double,Order> order_map;
Order a(1, 1.25);
Order b(2, 1.75);
Order c(3, 1.75);
Order d(4, 2.25);
Order e(5, 1.25);
order_map.insert(std::make_pair(a.get_price(), a)));
order_map.insert(std::make_pair(b.get_price(), b)));
order_map.insert(std::make_pair(c.get_price(), c)));
order_map.insert(std::make_pair(d.get_price(), d)));
order_map.insert(std::make_pair(e.get_price(), e)));
```

Using the `multimap`, I can search for one or more orders at a certain `price` using the `equal_range()` function.  Orders need to be ordered in ascending order by `price`, which `multimap` does automatically.  Orders also will be constantly added to the `multimap`, but they will also be constantly removed when orders are canceled.

As such, is there an efficient way to be able to remove a specific order using the `order_id` (assume all the `order_id` values are unique) without having to iterate through the whole `multimap`?

Comment: You can't search by order ID without iterating, since the ID not in the map's key. Why are you keying orders by price to begin with? This isn't a very good use-case for a multimap to begin with.

Comment: I actually need to keep two sorted lists of orders - one in ascending order (buy orders) and one in descending order (sell orders) to be able to match buy orders with sell orders when their prices cross.  I could put it in a vector but then I would have to call sort every time I added an order which would be very expensive.  Also, removing items from a vector are also expensive.

Comment: I actually figured out how I'm going to do it.  I'm going to create a second map std::unordered_map<int,std::multimap<double,Order>::iterator> so that whenever I insert a new Order to order_map, I insert the iterator of that new node into the secondary map which is mapped using the order_id value;  Since iterators for associative containers are not invalidated by new inserts/erases, it is safe to do a lookup on the second map.